# html5 canvas as a application

Tags: android, html, canvas

Does anyone know if there will be support for applications like that you download from the market to be written in [canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element)+javascript?

I know currently there is html5 and canvas support for the android browser but I am looking more for a solution for full screen games and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)?

Comment: PhoneGap enables you to wrap Web Apps (apps written in HTML/canvas/Javascript) into native app.

Answer (score 0):

After some research thanks to bhups there seems there are a few options[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework)